# Can data center remote hands service install new network card?

Tags: datacenter, server-setup

Long story short: I'm co-locating a standard server box in a data center in a faraway foreign country. I need to install a specialized network card that isn't sold or included by the OEM. I'd like to avoid having to fly half way around the world to pop in a NIC in the PCI.

I don't have much experience with data centers. The data center includes 10 hours of "remote hands" service in the contract. Would it be included in the remote hands service included by the data center to open the box and physically install the NIC?

Comment: What did the data center tell you when you asked them?

Answer (score 1):

Contracts can basically say anything, so without seeing your contract we can for certain say what is included.

The company I work for has had remote hands replace faulty RAM blocks, so remote hands can open a box and do physical tasks - actually that's among the things I would be quite confident having remote hands do, it's quite easy to verify it worked.